# Socket.io and PHP integration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I have a socket. I login to the socket from `header.php`. I'm calling `header.php` from all of my pages like this:

```
<?php
require_once("header.php");
?>
```

When I load all pages like this my socket is going to disconnect and then reconnect. I want to login just once on the socket but I don't know how can I do this. How can I prevent it from disconnecting and reconnecting?

`header.php` JavaScript code block:

```
<script  src='http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1xx0/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script>    
var socket = io.connect( "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1xx0/");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't. Web server starts each page load fresh. If you want a persistent connection with your socket maybe do that in a php cli app on the server and communicate with the browser using websockets etc.

Comment: @MuhammedAlmaz. Not sure if THE answer, but is maybe ONE way.
Could use AJAX, but ws is cool
(1) Launch websocket server (wss). In php run under CLI so is persistent, as web server loads and terminates.

(2) Your php socket app hangs off wss onconnect method.

(3) Your html page loads and connects to wss server by js.

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function wsinit() {
        socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8001/' ); 
}

(4) Now u have asynchronous persistent link between your app and the browser. 

(5) your app logs in to your ext socket etc etc.